# Stop table disappearing off end of page with stargazer

Tags: r, latex, knitr, stargazer

I have a .Rnw file that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Header}

<<table_mtcars, results = "asis">>=

stargazer(rbind(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars), summary = F)

@
\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

I can use `knitr::knit` to produce a .tex file and then convert this to a PDF. The resultant PDF looks like this:

[image]

Note how the table disappears off the end of page 2 and doesnt resurface on page 3. How can I get the table to continue on page 3 of the PDF using stargazer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know this is not currently supported by **stargazer**. I would recommend emailing the developer, who is usually very open to suggestions. The issue is that you need to use LaTeX's `longtable` environment instead of `tabular`, but this is the part that Stargazer doesn't seem to support.

You can create a workaround by doing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Header}

\Sexpr{library(knitr);gsub('tabular','longtable',knit(text="<<results = 'asis'>>=\nlibrary(stargazer)\nstargazer(rbind(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars), summary = FALSE, float = FALSE)\n@"))}

\end{document}
```

Basically, you're calling **knitr** within your .Rnw file in order to build the table, and `gsub` the `tabular` environment to `longtable`. When I run this, it comes out as three pages long.

Comment: stargazer developer here. Yes, this is correct. longtable is not currently supported, but is being planned for a future release.